# Deezer only returning previews-no streams. Using Android SDK

Tags: deezer

I'm trying to play back music using the Deezer Android API, following the sample code with the SDK.  I only get the 30s previews, never the stream.  Here is an snippet of the output returned:

```
{"id":"72306644","readable":true,"title":"Aura","link":"http:\/\/www.deezer.com\/track\/72306644","duration":236,"track_position":1,"disk_number":1,"rank":426293,"preview":"http:\/\/cdn-preview-e.deezer.com\/stream\/e0c84057c93e3cad84317d768413c0e3-0.mp3","stream":false,"artist"
{"id":"75491","name":"Lady GaGa","type":"artist"},"type":"track"}
```

Authentication is successful. I am signed in with a premium+ account.  Am I doing something incorrect or missing a step?

It seems to be returning streams now-perhaps it just took time for the account to be upgraded to premium+. It is not playing the stream however.i.e. no music being played.

It's pretty close to the sample code from the SDK and based on the online doc:
First create the player:

```
deezerConnect = new DeezerConnectImpl( parentActivity, APP_ID );
try {
   player = new DefaultPlayerFactory( parentActivity.getApplication(), 
   deezerConnect, new WifiOnlyNetworkStateChecker() ).createPlayer();
} catch (Exception e) {
   handleError( e );
}
```

Then make a call to get the tracks...

```
private void searchTracks(Album album) {
   long albumId = album.getId();
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString( "nb_items", "30");
   DeezerRequest request = new DeezerRequest( "album/"+albumId+"/tracks", bundle );
   request.setId( String.valueOf( albumId ) );
   deezerConnect.requestAsync( request, trackHandler );
}
```

Then after parsing the result in the trackHandler and creating a track object using gson it tries to play the track:

```
private void playTrack( Track track ) {
   if( player.getPlayerState() != PlayerState.STARTED ) {
      player.stop();
   }//if
   Log.d(TAGNAME, "Init track:" + track.getId() +":"+ deezerConnect.getAccessToken() +":"+   
   track.getStream() );

   if( track.hasStream() ) {
      player.init( track.getId(), track.getStream());
   } else {
      Log.d( TAGNAME,"Playing track preview:" + track.getId() );
      player.init( track.getId(), track.getPreview() );
   }//else

   player.setPlayerProgressInterval(1000);
   player.play();
}
```

Here are some snippets of the response output if it helps:

Response:{"data":[{"id":"17519569","readable":true,"title":"Dirty Paws","link":"http://www.deezer.com/track/17519569","duration":278,"track_position":1,"disk_number":1,"rank":399040,"preview":"http://cdn-preview-d.deezer.com/stream/def7161be8ee42ecb20036a136ad0cf6-2.mp3","stream":" ....long string of hex digits here... ","artist":{"id":"1581786","name":"Of Monsters And Men","type":"artist"},"type":"track"}

Comment: Hi, could you post a code sample showing how you make your request ?

Comment: Thanks.  I have the sample app working now.  I'll look into this more on my own to see what is different between that and my own code.

Comment: About the player not playing your tracks, try adding a PlayerErrorListener on your player to get more info on why the player doesn't play music.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the ErrorListener.  I added one and the error indicates something is wrong with the stream token. com.deezer.sdk.player.InvalidStreamTokenException: Invalid Stream Token
04-11 22:46:45.227: W/System.err(6571):   at com.deezer.sdk.player.impl.URLDecoderImpl.decodeStreamToken(Unknown Source)   I compared it to the one from the SDK sample app. (same song) and there are a few bytes different.

Comment: Hi, I think I figured out the problem.  The player needs to be created after authentication, which makes sense.

Comment: yes indeed the player can only read tracks after authentication (except for free radios).